# how to use a queryset expression in a then clause in conditional annotation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

i have two models, one of organizations and one with the membership and rol of an user in the organization

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,max_length=100, unique=True)

class Member(models.Model):
    user_request = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="member_user_request")
    user_second = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True, related_name="member_user_second")
    role = models.ForeignKey(RoleOrganization,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Rol'))
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Status'))
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Organization'))
```

and im trying to use a annotate with case clause where i want to get the role of an user in the organization with this expression:

```
my_organizations = Member.objects.filter(
        Q(user_request_id=self.request.user.id, status__name="accepted", type_request__name="request") |
        Q(user_second_id=self.request.user.id, status__name="accepted", type_request__name="invitation")
    )

Organization.objects.annotate(
        rol=Case(
            When(id__in=list(my_organizations.values_list('organization_id', flat=True)),
                 then=Value(my_organizations.get(organization_id=F('id')).role.name)),
            default=None, output_field=CharField()
        )
    )
```

the problem here is that the then expression doesn't get the id of the object in the main queryset, if i return in the then just the F('id') the expression gets the value of the id in the main queryset, but i can use a filter or any queryset expression with some values of the main object.

its there a way to accomplish this.
PS: im just putting part of the code here for cleanliness, but if you need to know more please let me know

Comment: Can you re-explain what you are trying to accomplish? I have a feeling you're approaching this from the wrong direction, but I'm not sure what data you're trying to pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

members = Member.objects.filter(
           Q(user_request_id=self.request.user.id, status__name="accepted", type_request__name="request") |
           Q(user_second_id=self.request.user.id, status__name="accepted", type_request__name="invitation")
        )

member_subquery = members.filter(organization=OuterRef('pk'))

organizations = Organization.objects.annotate(member_role=Subquery(member_subquery.values('role')[:1]))

print(organizations.values('member_role'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfectly, but, can you explain a little more how this accomplish my needs? thanks again

Comment: well, in `member_subquery`, I am using `OuterRef` to match the Outer `Organization` query when I am using `Subquery`. Here I can only annotate only one value from subquery, so I am using `[:1]` to get the first element of `Member` queryset values. I hope this info will help.